# How to set compile option to never in polymer serve?

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x, polymer-cli

When setting option compile to never in command polymer serve (polymer serve --compile never) I expect that it doesn't transpile my ES6 code to ES5 but it compiles for Firefox and not for Chrome so I believe polymer serve is still using auto as compile option.

- Firefox: imports rewritten as define([])
- Chrome:  imports kept untouched (import {} from)

polymer-cli v1.9.8

**EDIT:**

All imports are static

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about static ou dynamic imports?

Because since Firefox does not currently support dynamic `import()`, polymer serve has to convert them because otherwise the application wouldn't run at all. Even worse than not supporting them, Firefox throws a SyntaxError when they parse JavaScript files and see the aforementioned imports.

Comment: Static imports only right now, for the moment when I test on firefox I build my app, I don't want to use external libraries for es5 compatible modules and I already had an issue with polymer serve where allow-origin wasn't being actually use from the option in command line, but it doesn't seem to be the same problem this time.